# Как загрузить текстовый файл на веб-сервер и обработать его вне зависимости от имени файла

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть два файла "main_lib.py" и "main_prog.py". В файле "main_lib.py" хранятся функции. В файле "main_prog.py" хранится функция по загрузке файла и вызов разных функций из файла "main_lib.py".

"main_lib.py":

```
import re

path = 'content/input/Example.txt'
res = 'content/output/res.txt'
n=len(words_blood) 
m=len(words_pee)   
def convert_to_lower(path): # подготавливаем файл к чтению
    file = open(path, 'r')
    content = file.read().lower()
    file.close()

    file = open(path, 'w')
    file.write(content)
    file.close()
    return content
...
```

"main_prog.py":

```
import main_lib
import re
import cgi 
import os
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
upload = data[ 'filename' ] # к переменной присваиваем значение полного пути к загруженному файлу
filename = os.path.basename( upload.filename ) # к переменной присваиваем  краткое имя файла

def uploadFile(filename):
    path = 'content/input/'+filename
    with open( path, 'wb' ) as copy:
        copy.write( upload.file.read() ) # запишем копию загруженного файла на веб-сервер
    print( 'Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n' )
    print( '<!DOCTYPE HTML>' )
    print( '<html lang="en">' )
    print( '<head>' )
    print( '<meta charset="UTF-8">' )
    print( '<title>Python Response</title>' )
    print( '</head>' )
    print( '<body>' )
    print( '<h1>Файл Загружен:' , filename , '</h1>' )
    print( '<a href="index.html">Back</a>' )
    print( '</body>' )
    print( '</html>' )
    return path

path = uploadFile(filename)
main_lib.convert_to_lower(path)
...
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я могу загружать только один конкретный файл. Например "Example.txt", т.к. "main_lib.py" прописано path = 'content/input/Example.txt'. Если я загружу файл с другим названием, то функции не будут работать с этим файлом. Путь только-что загруженного файла записывается в переменную path в файле "main_prog.py". Как мне переменную path из файла "main_prog.py" скопировать в переменную path в "main_lib.py"?

Comment: Так, как в коде написано, переменная path уже передается в функцию ``convert_to_lower`` (в строчке ``main_lib.convert_to_lower(path)``) и ничего изменять не надо.

Comment: Это верно. Переменная path уже передается в функцию convert_to_lower, но если я уберу переменную path из файла main_lib, то функции перестанут работать. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы переменная path в main_lib знала, точный путь до файла. То, что я сделал является неправильным решением. path = 'content/input/Example.txt' может работать только с конкретным файлом, а именно Example.txt. Мне нужно, чтобы программа могла работать с любым файлом, вне зависимости от имени файла.

Comment: Функции перестанут работать, если main_lib.py просто запускать отдельно. Если же функции вызывать из main_prog.py с передачей аргумента, то всё будет работать.

Comment: Вы говорите, что у меня все правильно. Так почему же моя программа может работать только с одним конкретным файлом?

Comment: Потому что запускаете ее отдельно, а не вызываете функции из main_prog.py. См. предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Я не понимаю. Т.е. если я делаю так `content = main_lib.convert_to_lower(path)`, то вызываю функцию отдельно из main_lib? А как тогда вызвать  main_prog?

Comment: Извините, я не могу работать учебником. Исходя из вашего описания ваш код работает так как надо. Если не работает, значит исправьте описание или код. Или задайте новый вопрос.